# tab bar controller tab missing title

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is really a strange problem.  I have a tab bar controller with 5 tabs.  Each tab has its own image and title.  I deleted the associated nib file for one of the tabs and created it from scratch.  Now everything is fine except that when I run the program, that particular tab is missing its title and image.  All other tabs are fine.  Also when I look at the main view nib file shows all tab titles and images.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them programmatically,

```
 yourViewController.title = @"Title";
 yourViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works but do you have any idea why it is overwritten?

Comment: Is there anyway in iphone debug tool to break when a value changes?

Comment: The compiler sets sets outlets in the IB before generating the views through code. so naturally, because of the precedence of views, it calls from the program will overwrite IB values.

Comment: I understand why the code overwrites it.  What I don't understand is why without having any code to overwrite any tab, one of the tabs is missing the image and title.

Comment: Yes, it would work. It would be a problem with not connecting the outlets properly.

Comment: This is my original question.  What could be the reason one of the tabs from 5 tabs has problem connecting to outlets.